# getting list using foreach in javascript inside php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, foreach

I have a JS function inside my PHP view file. What I want to do is enable a button when the function verifies that the input does not exist in the database. So here's my function:

```
var name = 0; 
$("#edit-name").on("change", edit_name);

function edit_name() {
    if ($('#edit-name').val()== ""){
        $('#edit-name').addClass('required');
        $('#warning').html('Please fill required input.');
        name = 0;
    }

    else {
        <?php foreach ($name_list as $list) { ?>
            if ($('#edit-name').val() == '<?php echo $list->name ?>') {
                name = 0;
                $('#warning').html('Name already exists');
            }

            else {
                $('#warning').html('');
                name = 1;
            }
        <?php } ?>
    }

    enableButton();
}

function enableButton(){
    if (name == 1)
        document.getElementById('edit-btn').disabled = false;
    else
        document.getElementById('edit-btn').disabled = true;
}
```

**I don't know what's wrong but even if the inputs are correct, my code is not working properly:** It works when it checks if there is an input or not. But nothing happens to the button even if I input a new name. When I input an existing name, the warning doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your HTML-Code that is generated than you see your mistake.

If you have for example a Array ["name" => "test"], ["name" => "test2"] than you view generates the following HTML:

```
        if ($('#edit-name').val() == 'test') {
            name = 0;
            $('#warning').html('Name already exists');
        }

        else {
            $('#warning').html('');
            name = 1;
        }


        if ($('#edit-name').val() == 'test1') {
            name = 0;
            $('#warning').html('Name already exists');
        }

        else {
            $('#warning').html('');
            name = 1;
        }
```

You see "else" is always true.

You need to write:

```
 <? 
 $stringarray = "";

 foreach($name_list as $list){
   $stringarray .= '"'.$list->name.'",';
 }

 // Del last ,
 $stringarray = substr($stringarray,0,-1);
 ?>

 var names = [<?php echo $stringarray;?>];
 if (names.indexOf($('#edit-name').val()) != -1) {
            name = 0;
            $('#warning').html('Name already exists');
        }else {
            $('#warning').html('');
            name = 1;
        }
```